# $A'=\mathbb{N}$ for $A=\{{n + 1/m}\mid n,m\in\mathbb N\}$

Tags: metric-spaces

I have to prove in $\mathbb{R}$ that $A'=   \mathbb{N} $, where $$A=\{n + 1/m\mid m,n\in\mathbb N\}.$$
Let me first describe my thought on this one.So in order for these 2 sets to be equal it means that
$A'=\{1,2,3...\}$ so for $x=1,2,3..$ I have to prove that the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon = 1$ will have infinite points of $A$ in it. So we know from Archimedes that we can find $n < 1/n_o$ for every $n,n_o$ real numbers. So i can find infinite points around that $x$.

Is this correct or am I missing something

Comment: Do you mean $$A=\left\{n+1/m\mid m,n\in\mathbb N\right\}?$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes m,n are real numbers

Comment: Is $A’$ the boundary of $A?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in my book A' are all the points lets say $x$ that B(x,e)-{x} intersection A is different from the empty set